# How to include Non-AscII character in python appengine send html mail

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, email

My problem is that I want to compose an email in python environment of google appengine. 
When I add Greek characters to the body of my message I get:
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xce'

```
megssage.html = """
<html>
<body>
    παραδειγμα
</body>
</html>"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: @Chris this means that you messed something up. Here is a working code with it http://pastebin.com/z7zBM2it . Make sure that the shebang is right at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Chris No, 'u' should be prefixed to the string literal.